# Decoupling theory by diagonalising the Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, hamiltonian, linear-algebra

I have a Hamiltonian of the form

$H = 2k(\alpha \alpha^* -\beta \beta^*) -2\lambda (\alpha\beta^* + \beta \alpha^* )$

and I'd like to decouple the $\alpha$'s and $\beta$'s if possible. I know I need to diagonalise the Hamiltonian, like this:

$H = (\alpha, \alpha^*, \beta, \beta^* ) \begin{pmatrix} 0& k & 0 &-\lambda \\
k & 0 & -\lambda & 0 \\
0 & -\lambda & 0 & -k\\
-\lambda &0 &-k &0 
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ 
\alpha^* \\
\beta\\
\beta^*
\end{pmatrix} $

Then use $H = PDP^{-1}$. I can use Mathematica to find the diagonal matrix and $P$ but then I'm stuck how to use this to decouple the $\alpha$'s and $\beta$'s. I end up with

$H =(\alpha, \alpha^*, \beta, \beta^* ) P D P^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ 
\alpha^* \\
\beta\\
\beta^*
\end{pmatrix} $,

but of course multiplying this out gets me back where I started. I think I'm misunderstanding something in the process. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Let $\left(\begin{array}{c} a\\a^*\\b\\b^*\end{array} \right) = P^{-1}\left(\begin{array}{c} \alpha\\\alpha^*\\\beta\\\beta^*\end{array} \right)$ and your Hamiltonian is diagonal in the $a$ and $b$ operators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write
\begin{align}
H=(\alpha,\alpha^*,\beta,\beta^*)M (\alpha,\alpha^*,\beta,\beta^*)^\top
\end{align}

You need first to find the matrix $P$ that will diagonalize your $M$ so that
\begin{align}
P^{-1}MP=D\, ,\qquad \Rightarrow \qquad 
M=P D P^{-1}
\end{align}
where $D$ is diagonal and contains the eigenvalues of $M$ on the diagonal.

Next, you go to a new basis $P^{-1}(\alpha,\alpha^*,\beta,\beta^*)^\top= (a,a^*,b,b^*)^\top$ so that
\begin{align}
H&=(\alpha,\alpha^*,\beta,\beta^*)PDP^{-1} (\alpha,\alpha^*,\beta,\beta^*)^\top 
\nonumber \\
&= 
(a,a^*,b,b^*)^\top D (a,a^*,b,b^*)^\top 
\end{align}
will be diagonal in the new variables.

The matrix $P$ is obtained by arranging the orthonormal eigenvectors of $M$ in columns, and you need the eigenvalues of $M$ to get the eigenvectors.  Luckily for you, notice that
\begin{align}
M\cdot M= (k^2+\lambda^2)\mathbb{I}
\end{align}
so the eigenvalues of $M$ are $\pm \sqrt{k^2+\lambda^2}$, each eigenvalue occurring twice.  The job of finding each eigenvector is systematic, with the twist that you will need to make sure that both eigenvectors with eigenvalue $+\sqrt{k^2+\lambda^2}$ are orthogonal to each other, and both eigenvectors with eigenvalue $-\sqrt{k^2+\lambda^2}$ are orthogonal to each other as orthogonality of eigenvectors corresponding with the same eigenvalue must be enforced "by hand".